# Can I use JSON auth file with Cloud Firestore Client with php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I am testing the cloud Firestore php client library ( https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/master/Firestore )

In the cloud Storage Client,this code works:

```
   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

// Authenticating with keyfile data.
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/keyfile.json'), true)
]);

// Authenticating with a keyfile path.
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/keyfile.json'
]);

// Providing the Google Cloud project ID.
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => 'myProject'
]);
```

I want to know if is possible to use the same code to initialize the  Firestore Client? Especially the part with Json.

It works fine with projetctId but I want to use it with keyFile or keyFilePath if possible.

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP libraries and other languages is better and is more practical use the environment variables instead declare the JSON key path and the project in the code

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT - name of the project
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS - Path to JSON file
```

This method guarantees the compatibility of the code with some serverless GCP products like Cloud Functions and App Engine.

Additionally, it is a good practice because if you upload this code to a repository the credentials not gonna be included in your code

To declare your credentials on your code for firestore  client, check the following code:

```
 $db = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
        'keyFilePath' =>  '/path/to/keyfile.json',

    ]);
```

This is not mentioned on the Firestore documentation but in the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore/blob/master/src/FirestoreClient.php) of the class Firestoreclient appears all options that you can use to initialize the client

```
@type string $apiEndpoint A hostname with optional port to use in
      place of the service's default endpoint.
@type string $projectId The project ID from the Google Developer's
      Console.
@type CacheItemPoolInterface $authCache A cache for storing access
      tokens. **Defaults to** a simple in memory implementation.
@type array $authCacheOptions Cache configuration options.
@type callable $authHttpHandler A handler used to deliver Psr7
      requests specifically for authentication.
@type callable $httpHandler A handler used to deliver Psr7 requests.
      Only valid for requests sent over REST.
@type array $keyFile The contents of the service account credentials
      .json file retrieved from the Google Developer's Console.
      Ex: `json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true)`.
@type string $keyFilePath The full path to your service account
      credentials .json file retrieved from the Google Developers
      Console.
@type int $retries Number of retries for a failed request. **Defaults
      to** `3`.
@type array $scopes Scopes to be used for the request.
@type bool $returnInt64AsObject If true, 64 bit integers will be
      returned as a {@see Google\Cloud\Core\Int64} object for 32 bit
      platform compatibility. **Defaults to** false.
```